# Adding metadata into Stanford coreNLP input

Tags: stanford-nlp

I have a large corpus of sentences (~ 1.1M) to parse through Stanford Core NLP but in the output I get more sentences than in the input, probably the system segments some sentences beyond the given segmentation into lines.

To control what happens I would like to include "tags" into the input. These tags should be recognizable in the output and should not affect parsing.

Something like

```
<0001>
I saw a man with a telescope .
</0001>
```

or

```
#0001#
I saw a man with a telescope .
#/0001#
```

I have tried many formats, in all cases the "tag" has been parsed as if it were part of the text.

Is there some way to tell the parser "do not parse this, just keep it *as is* in the output"?

===A few hours later===

As I'm getting no answer, here is an example: I would like to process the sentence “Manon espérait secrètement y revoir un garçon qui l'avait marquée autrefois.” that carries tag `151_0_4`. I imagined to write the tag between two rows of equal signs on a separate line, followed by a period, to be sure that the tag will, at worst, be processed as a separate sentence:

```
=====151_0_4======.
Manon espérait secrètement y revoir un garçon qui l'avait marquée autrefois.
=====151_0_4======.
```

And here is what this produced:

```
(ROOT (SENT (NP (SYM =)) (NP (SYM =) (PP (SYM =) (NP (SYM =) (PP (SYM =) (NP (NUM 151_0_4) (SYM =) (SYM =) (NP (SYM =) (PP (SYM =) (NP (SYM =) (SYM =))))))))) (PUNCT .)))
```

As you see the tags are definitely considered as being part of the sentence, no way to separate them from it.

Same thing happened with XML-like tags `<x151_0_4>` or tags using the hash character...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your current data is strictly one sentence per line, then by far the easiest thing to do is to just leave it like that and to give the option `-ssplit.eolonly=true`.

There unfortunately isn't an option to pass through certain kinds of meta-data or delimiters without attempting to parse or process them. However, you can indicate that they should not be made part of other sentences by means of the `ssplit.boundaryTokenRegex` or `ssplit.boundaryMultiTokenRegex` properties. However, your choices are then either to just delete them (see `ssplit.tokenPatternsToDiscard`) or else to process them as weird sentences, which you'd then need to clean up.

Comment: It didn't worked. I entered a file with 15,065 lines of text (all ending with a period, an exclamation mark or a question mark) and in the output I got 15,100 parsed sentences. I used the `-ssplit.eolonly=true` option.

Comment: In fact it worked with `-ssplit.newlineIsSentenceBreak always`

Comment: Well good that there's a solution! But `eolonly=true` should also work. If you wanted to email me, or put on GitHub, an extract that generates more sentences than lines of text, we could try to fix it....